# How to add an array with attribute 'a' into another with attr. 'b' based on the attributes of third array with attr. ['a', 'b']

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have 3 arrays as follows:

```
 Categories:

    0: {id: "123", name: "Cat 1"},
    1: {id: "456", name: "Cat 2"},
    2: {id: "789", name: "Cat 3"}


    Account Category:

    0: {categoryId: "123", supportId:"john@gmail.com" },
    1: {categoryId: "456", supportId:"john@gmail.com" },
    2: {categoryId: "789", supportId:"sherlock@gmail.com" },
    3: {categoryId: "123", supportId:"bikal@gmail.com"}


    Accounts:

    0: {email: "john@gmail.com", firstName: "john"},
    1: {email: "sherlock@gmail.com", firstName: "sherlock"},
    2: {email: "bikal@gmail.com", firstName: "bikal"}
```

I have to add:

- "Categories" into it's specific "Accounts" based on the "id" from "Categories"
- "email" from "Accounts"

The only way that links them is another array "Account Category" which has both the fields.

I'm confused as to how to accomplish this. I'm fine with using lodash, but even with that I'm not sure how to perform this task.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Edit:
The output should look like this:

```
Accounts:

0: {categories:[{id: "456", name:"Cat 2"}, {id: "123", name: "Cat 1"}], email: "john@gmail.com", firstName: "john"},
1: {categories:[{id: "789", name:"Cat 3"}], email: "sherlock@gmail.com", firstName: "sherlock"},
2: {categories:[{id: "123", name:"Cat 1"}], email: "bikal@gmail.com", firstName: "bikal"}
```

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking us to write code for you...

Comment: @JackBashford I've edited to code for the expected output. Please look into it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple to do - `find` the correct `supportId` based on `categoryId`, then get the `email` and `firstName` out, and return the properties you want:

```js
const Categories = [{id: "123", name: "Cat 1"},{id: "456", name: "Cat 2"},{id: "789", name: "Cat 3"}];
const AccountCategory = [{categoryId: "123", supportId:"john@gmail.com" },{categoryId: "456", supportId:"john@gmail.com" },{categoryId: "789", supportId:"sherlock@gmail.com" },{categoryId: "123", supportId:"bikal@gmail.com"}];
const Accounts = [{email: "john@gmail.com", firstName: "john"},{email: "sherlock@gmail.com", firstName: "sherlock"},{email: "bikal@gmail.com", firstName: "bikal"}];

const res = Categories.map(({ id, name }) => {
  const { supportId } = AccountCategory.find(({ categoryId }) => categoryId == id);
  const { email, firstName } = Accounts.find(({ email, firstName }) => email == supportId);
  return { id, name, email, firstName };
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: The question is unclear and is missing any effort. Its kinda spoon-feeding in my POV. Also, in `AccountCategory`, if you notice, there are 2 emails for categoryId `123`. That part is unanswer in requirement(*not a problem statement as no effort*) and will attract unwanted comments/votes

Comment: @Rajesh look at the code again, I have edited it with the expected output.

Comment: @JackBashford as commented, this is a requirement and it will change as we go into discussion and ask question. That will make your answer void. Hence, its always better to have a problem statement.